# Trouble adding onclick events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, dom-events

Every time I try to add an `onclick` event to a newly created button, the event seems to get triggered before the button is even pressed. Here is how I've been trying to go about it:

```
var que = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var text = document.createTextNode("Question1");
que.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(que);
que.setAttribute("onclick", function1());
```

Each time `function1()` is run before I even have a chance to press the button. Does anyone have any ideas of why?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
que.setAttribute("onclick",function() {function1();})
```

or this:

```
que.onclick = function() {function1();}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `que.setAttribute("onclick", "function1()");`

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/L5s1x1nz/